# An Error with simple KeyListener app

Tags: java

Basiclly i am a begginer proggrammer, i know little bit from C#, C++
and now i am learning Java for building Android apps.
i am learning java from youtube from brandonio production, very helpful. http://www.youtube.com/user/BrandonioProductions?feature=watch

this is the full code:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class KeyListenerApp 
extends Applet
implements KeyListener{
private Rectangle rect; //The rectangle that moving
private ArrayList<Integer> keysDown;
public void init()
{
    rect = new Rectangle(0,0,50,50);
    this.addKeyListener(this);
}
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    setSize(500,500);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2.fill(rect);
}
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(keysDown.contains(new Integer(e.getKeyCode())))
    {
        keysDown.add(new Integer(e.getKeyCode()));
    }
    moveRect();
}
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    keysDown.remove(new Integer(e.getKeyCode()));
}
public void moveRect()
{
    int x = rect.x;
    int y = rect.y;
    if (keysDown.contains(KeyEvent.VK_UP))
        y -= 2;
    if (keysDown.contains(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN))
        y += 2;
    if (keysDown.contains(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT))
        x -= 2;
    if (keysDown.contains(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT))
        x += 2;
    rect.setLocation(x, y);
    repaint();
}
@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
}
}
```

This is the full error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at KeyListenerApp.keyPressed(KeyListenerApp.java:34)
    at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at KeyListenerApp.keyReleased(KeyListenerApp.java:44)
    at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Sorry for not posting the code in here at first, i tought that it will be more comfortable for you if it will be seperate from the question.

Thank you

Here is the working code:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class KeyListenerApp 
extends Applet
implements KeyListener{

private Rectangle rect; //The rectangle that moving

private ArrayList<Integer> keysDown;

public void init()
{
    rect = new Rectangle(0,0,50,50);
    this.addKeyListener(this);
    keysDown = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    setSize(500,500);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2.fill(rect);
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    if(keysDown.contains(new Integer(e.getKeyCode())) == false)
    {
        keysDown.add(new Integer(e.getKeyCode()));
    }

    moveRect();
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    keysDown.remove(new Integer(e.getKeyCode()));

}

public void moveRect()
{
    int x = rect.x;
    int y = rect.y;

    if (keysDown.contains(KeyEvent.VK_UP))
        y -= 2;

    if (keysDown.contains(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN))
        y += 2;

    if (keysDown.contains(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT))
        x -= 2;

    if (keysDown.contains(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT))
        x += 2;

    rect.setLocation(x, y);
    repaint();
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {


}

}
```

what cause the error:

```
if(keysDown.contains(new Integer(e.getKeyCode())) == false)
{
    keysDown.add(new Integer(e.getKeyCode()));
}
```

This code was like this before i fixed it:

```
if(keysDown.contains(new Integer(e.getKeyCode())))
{
    keysDown.add(new Integer(e.getKeyCode()));
}
```

The Error happend because I said in the code:
if something exsits then add him, and it was suppose to add him only if he wasn't exsits.

Comment: if you have found the solution, either accept some answer, or post you own answer in the answer tab and not in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
private ArrayList<Integer> keysDown;
```

You never create an instance of this object, hence the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: You need to put `keysDown = new ArrayList<Integer>();` in your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

keysDown is NULL! It hasn't been initialized.
You shold do:

```
keysDown = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

in some method before using it, and also fill your list with ascii keys.

Comment: should i put "keysDown = new ArrayList<Integer>();" at the the init method ?

Comment: Yep. That way you won't get the exception. @kingston951

Comment: Also after the assignment, add the ascii keys you expect to evaluate, for example: `keysDown.add(32);` which is space bar.

Comment: Well I'm happy for you. Please mark one of these answers as correct.